# change detection on frames for different videos

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library, video-processing

I am analyzing a video and I am recording a device performing some action(tablet). And I record it for two different devices. But the "content" is the same.I put the contents in quotes cause the lighting, aspect ratio,borders are different from one video to another.But the action going on both the videos are same.

You will get a better idea of what I am trying to ask, if you see the four images.

Image1 (Device1)
[image: Device1_change1]

Image2 (Device1)
[image: Device1_change2]

Image3 (Device2)
[image: Device2_change1]

Image4 (Device2)
[image: Device2_change2]

First two images are from device1 and the next two from Device2.
Is there a way that I can detect a change in the frame like (first image to the second). The action is zooming in and when its zoomed to a point and the change is caught(Image2). Similarly, I want to catch the same change in the other video too.
So something like trying to catch Image 4 from Image3.

I have used algorithms like Manhattan, FD, Color histogram. None of them works fine.

Comment: Need more explanation on what you mean by _and when it is zoomed to a point and the change is caught_. Won't a simple difference of images followed by a threshold be able to detect the change? If, on the other hand, you want to detect change based on the _content_, you might need more sophisticate approaches like SIFT feature matching, etc.

Comment: What I mean by "zoomed to a point" , there are transitions when you zoom in. So in the Image2 you can see that there is Visual change compare to Image1 and there are couple algos like Manhattan which catches these visual change. Will I cannot scale this to different devices. As in, you can see the difference of the recordings between Image1,2 and Image3,4 . Is there a generic algo to catch the same change?

Answer (score 0):

You might calculate the average word height and width of the texts of the reference frames (image 3) and comapare it with that of the testing images (image 4). This would be able to detect the zoom-in action. To do this i think binarization followed by connected component analysis should suffice. This should give you an estimate of the magnification. There are many algorithms availabe in google.

Then you can use image interpolation techniques to to do the zooming.

Good Luck.